# How to define width of :before pseudo element relative to containing element

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, pseudo-element

I want to place an image circle on specific words.

```
<p>
   <span class="Subjekt">Vater</span>
   <span class="Praedikat">bringt</span>
</p>
```

with

```
.Subjekt:before {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(images/markup/einkreisen1.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px;
    content:"";
}
```

Which works fine. But with a fixed size.

Is there a way to define the width of the pseudo element relative to the .Subjekt element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `relative` positioning for the `before` element with respect to `Subjekt` element.

See example below:

1. Give `relative` position for `Subjekt`.
2. Try varying the `width` and `height` of `Subjekt` (Note that I have set it to `inline-block` too for the element as `inline` elements- which is the default display type- will not take the width or height)
3. Set `height` and `width` of the `before` element as 100%.
4. I gave `z-index: -1` to the place the `before` behind.

```css
.Subjekt {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Subjekt:before {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    content:"";
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p>
   <span class="Subjekt">Vater</span>
   <span class="Praedikat">bringt</span>
</p>
```

Hope you can take it forward from here. Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: I struggled a lot and wasted hours due to the responsive nature of my element. but this answer solved my issue very well. Thanks a lot, man. :-)